# Can't run Frama-C on 13.04 after installation

Tags: installation, apt, 13.04

I have installed [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) on 13.04 via `apt-get`.

However, after installation, I can not run it. When I type `frama-c` in terminal; nothing happens.

Also `frama-c` doesn't appear in the dash! I have checked software center and it was checked as installed and also I got output from `frama-c --version`

How can I detect the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `frama-c-gui` in a terminal.

`frama-c` is a command line application and does not have graphical front end.

`frama-c-gui` is a graphical front end to it and is installed when you install `frama-c`

From the [Man Page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/frama-c-gui.1.html)

**DESCRIPTION**

**frama-c**  is  a  suite of tools dedicated to the analysis of source code written in C.  It gathers  several  static  analysis  techniques  in  a single  collaborative  framework.  This  framework  can  be extended by additional plugins placed in the $FRAMAC_PLUGIN directory. The command

**frama-c -help** will provide the full list of the plugins that are currently installed.

**frama-c-gui** is the graphical user interface of  frama-c.   It  features the same options as the command-line version.

**frama-c.byte** and **frama-c-gui.byte** are  the  ocaml  bytecode versions of the command-line and graphical user interface respectively.

By default, Frama-C  recognizes  **.c**  files  as  C  files  needing  pre-processing  and  **.i** files as C files having been already pre-processed. Some plugins may extend the list of  recognized  files.  Pre-processing can be customized through the **-cpp-command** and **-cpp-extra-args** options.